# implementing foreach (doseq) in clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure, lisp, scheme, sicp

i'm working through SICP - one exercise is to implement foreach (doseq). **This is an academic exercise**. In clojure, this is what I came up with:

```
(defn for-each [proc, items]
  (if (empty? items) nil
      (do
        (proc (first items))
        (recur proc (rest items)))))
```

but, i'm a little murky about if `do` is cheating, because `do` is a special form in clojure and i don't think anything like that has been introduced yet in SICP. **is there a more minimalist answer?**

Here's another attempt which only executes proc on the last element:

```
(defn for-each-2 [proc, items]
  (let [f (first items)
        r (rest items)]
    (if (empty? r)
      (proc f)
      (recur proc r))))
```

Comment: You're fine.  SICP is being tricksy here.  See the very small text of footnote 3 in: http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-20.html#call_footnote_Temp_323.  Anytime you're doing a `cond` in SICP, you've got an implicit `begin` in play for each clause of the `cond`.  And `begin` in SICP is pretty much `do` in Clojure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`doseq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doseq) and you're all set. For example:

```
(doseq [e '(1 2 3)]
       (prn e))
```

Will print:

```
1
2
3
nil
```

**EDIT :**

If you want to implement `for-each` by hand and using as few special forms as possible, here's another alternative, although it ends up being almost as short as yours:

```
(defn for-each [f l]
  (cond (empty? l) nil
        :else (do (f (first l)) 
                  (recur f (rest l)))))
```

Interestingly, the same procedure could have been written more succinctly in Scheme, the Lisp dialect used in SICP:

```
(define (for-each f l)
  (cond ((null? l) null)
        (else (f (first l))
              (for-each f (rest l)))))
```

Comment: yes, i want to implement that with as few special forms as possible.

Comment: @DustinGetz I updated my answer with another option, but really that's about as short as it can get

Comment: And no, at least in Clojure you can't avoid `do` for indicating that more than one statement needs to be executed in sequence

Comment: ah. so the difference is that in scheme, the else clause is a list of expressions to 'do'. clojure makes this explicit, hence the required dependency on some sort of special form that can execute a list of statements. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt. It just carries function execution in an inner loop.

```
(defn for-each [fun, xs]
  (loop [fun fun
         xs xs
         action nil]
    (if (first xs)
      (recur fun (rest xs) (fun (first xs)))
      xs)))
```

Comment: thats quite clever - it exploits the fact that the bracketed part of a loop is a list of bindings executed in order. now that i understand, this is equivalent complexity to the `do` approach.

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful. I thought once again and decided `action nil` would be fine.